# Windows: Window position X coordinate not accurate

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, window

I want to get the (accurate) on-screen `X` and `Y` coordinates of a window ([the client area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16907689/3764804)). My problem is that I have to define a horizontal shift which has to be added onto the `X` coordinate to get the correct result:

```
#include <windows.h>

inline int get_title_bar_thickness(const HWND window_handle)
{
    RECT window_rectangle, client_rectangle;
    GetWindowRect(window_handle, &window_rectangle);
    GetClientRect(window_handle, &client_rectangle);
    const int height = window_rectangle.bottom - window_rectangle.top -
        (client_rectangle.bottom - client_rectangle.top);
    const int width = window_rectangle.right - window_rectangle.left -
        (client_rectangle.right - client_rectangle.left);
    return height - width / 2;
}

#define HORIZONTAL_SHIFT 8

/**
 * Gets the window position of the window handle
 * excluding the title bar and populates the x and y coordinates
 */
inline void get_window_position(const HWND window_handle, int* x, int* y)
{
    RECT rectangle;
    const auto window_rectangle = GetWindowRect(window_handle, &rectangle);
    const auto title_bar_thickness = get_title_bar_thickness(window_handle);
    if (window_rectangle)
    {
        *x = rectangle.left + HORIZONTAL_SHIFT;
        *y = rectangle.top + title_bar_thickness;
    }
}
```

The issue can be observed by moving the window programmatically:

```
const auto window_handle = FindWindow(nullptr, "Command Prompt");
SetWindowPos(window_handle, nullptr, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

I would expect this `SetWindowPos()` call to perfectly place the window into the upper left corner of my screen but there is some space left between the window and the screen border (exactly 8 pixels). Is there a way to assure that this horizontal offset is automatically considered? This might be related to laptops so how to make this behave as expected?

Comment: it should be just `*x = rectangle.left; *y = rectangle.top;` Also it is not clear how this is related to `SetWindowPos` issues (which I can not reproduce)

Comment: This obviously happens because you add `HORIZONTAL_SHIFT` (which is 8) to the `X`.

Comment: On Windows 10, the difference is given by GetWindowRect and  DwmGetWindowAttribute with **DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS**, which is usually = 7

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to retrieve the client area in screen coordinates. To do so, call `GetClientRect`, followed by `ClientToScreen`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by [`Castorix`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4452971/castorix), the horizontal shift can be retrieved.

```
#include <dwmapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dwmapi.lib")

inline int get_horizontal_shift(const HWND window_handle)
{
    RECT window_rectangle, frame_rectangle;
    GetWindowRect(window_handle, &window_rectangle);
    DwmGetWindowAttribute(window_handle,
                         DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &frame_rectangle, sizeof(RECT));

    return frame_rectangle.left - window_rectangle.left;
}
```

The code is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34143777/3764804) post. The return value is `7` on my machine.